# Error wher use Json serialization on graalVM

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I would like to use rest API to retrieve info for my app write whith gluon-mobile and graalvm. How I can serialize my data? I have tried Gson and Jackson and on ios Device the result string of serialization is null

Comment: Be aware that serialization is done via reflection, so basically all you need to do is add your model classes to the reflection list

Comment: Ok, I founded my error, I use httsp connections and I receive this error:

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
  at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
  at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:320)
  at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263) 

I can do?

Comment: There is an issue with SSL/HTTPS: it requires a `cacerts` file that it is usually located in the JDK/security folder. Since we are building a native-image, somehow we have to create it with a bundled copy of that file... This should be handled internally by Substrate (https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/issues/287)